# Characterizing the big Bruhat cell of the universal Chevalley groups over $\mathbb C$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, weyl-group, chevalley-groups

Is there a simple characterization of the big Bruhat cell of the universal (simply-connected) Chevalley groups over $\mathbb C$?

For example, it is known that the Borel subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb C)$ are the upper triangular matrices and the longest Weyl element $w_0$ is the permutation matrix for $(1 2.. n)$.
Furthermore if for every $1 ≤ i \neq j ≤ n$ let $E_{i,j}$ be the subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(n, \mathbb C)$ consisting of the matrices with $1$ on the diagonal and zero on the $(r, s)$-entry whenever $1 ≤ r \neq s ≤ n$
and $(r, s) \neq (i, j)$ and define $U_{i,j} := \langle E_{r,s} \mid j < s\,or\,j = s\,\mbox{ and }\,r ≤ i\rangle$.
 
Than for every $x$ in the big Bruhat cell we can write $x=bw_0u$ for $b \in B$ and $u \in U_{n-1,n}$.

Is there something similar for the general case?

Comment: Exactly the same is true for any Chevellay group: one chooses any lifting of the longest Weyl group element $w_0$ to $G$ and then the big cell is $Bw_0B$ (or $Bw_0U$ if you wish, where $U$ is the unipotent radical of $B$). This is the maximal dimension cell of the Bruhat decomposition.

Comment: In the simply connected case one can show that the big cell $U^{-} B$ is a principal open set, see Lemma 4.5 in "Properties and linear representations of Chevalley Groups" by Borel (Seminar on algebraic groups). The original reference is "Certains schémas de groupes semi-simples" by Chevalley, pp. 226-228. In your example for $G = SL_n(\mathbb{C})$, the big cell corresponds to matrices $(g_{ij})$ for which the $n$ leading principal minors are nonzero.

Comment: Yes, but how do I find the longest Weyl group element, the Borel subgroup and it's unipotent radical?

Comment: @Ami:  I think the point is that there are solid  proofs for existene of a Borel subgroup (corresponding to any fixed choice of positive roots, say), and similarly for the longest element of $W$.    To describe these explicitly in the case of exceptional simple algebraic groups may be difficult, of course.    But the root systems are well-studied.  Anyway, some of your restrictions on the big group are unnecessary here (for example, simple connectedness).

Comment: By the way, I came here from one of your more [recent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338323/nontrivial-relations-of-the-irreducible-root-systems) questions, and want to mention also here that $(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)$ is *not* the long element of $A_{n - 1}$; it is a Coxeter element, and has length $n$.  The long element is $(1\ n)(2\ n - 1)(3\ n - 2)\dotsb$, and has length $n(n - 1)/2$.

Comment: Also, more or less correspondingly, your decomposition of your Bruhat cell, while almost correct, is not the relevant one for the big Bruhat cell.  For the big cell (corresponding to the long element $w_{\text{long}}$), you need the full unipotent radical $U = U_{1, n}$ (if I understand the notation); that is, the product map $B \times U \to B w_{\text{long}}B$ given by $(b, u) \mapsto b n u$, for any fixed $n$ lifting $w_{\text{long}}$ (sorry, group element $n$, not integer $n$), is an isomorphism of varieties (though not of groups), and you cannot replace $U$ by $U_{n - 1, n}$.

Comment: Finally, note of course that your $U_{i, j}$ is probably the appropriate thing in $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb Z)$, but not in $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb C)$; you need $x_{r, s}(t) = 1 + t(E_{r, s} - 1)$ for all $t \in \mathbb C$, not just the various $x_{r, s}(n) = E_{r, s}^n$ with $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you, I was misinformed about the longest element of the Weyl group, know the use of $U_{n-1,n}$ make sense.