# Nontrivial relations of the irreducible root systems

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, root-systems, weyl-group

For the root system of the type $A_n$, the roots are $\alpha _{i,j}$, $1\le i\neq j\le n$, 
we have the nontrivial relations  $(x_{i,j} (t), x_{j,k}(u)) = x_{i,k}(tu)$ if $i, j, k$ are distinct. ($x_{i,j}$ are the elements of the root subgroup $U_{\alpha_{i,j}}$)
I'm looking for sources that lists similar commutator relation in the diffrent root systems, and also the permutation of the longest Weyl element on the roots.

Specifically, I'm trying to find relations that enables me to move down the root element by hight using the highest root element and the longest Weyl element.

For example in $A_n$, $(\omega_0 x_{i-1,n}(t)\omega_0^{-1},x_{1,n}(u))=(x_{i,1}(t),x_{1,n}(u))=x_{i,n}(tu)$ ($\omega_0$ is the longest Weyl element and $x_{1,n}$ the highest root element).

Comment: I think that the $\omega_0$ (I prefer $w_0$) conjugate of $\alpha_{i - 1, n}$ is $\alpha_{n - i + 2, 1}$, not $\alpha_{i, 1}$.  Also note that it doesn't make sense to conjugate an element of $G$ by an element of the Weyl group $W$; the latter is defined only up to translation by the maximal torus $T$, and which translate you choose affects the conjugation on root subgroups.

Comment: Anyway, the commutation relations among root groups are known as "Chevalley's commutator formula".  See, for example, §5.2 of Carter's [Simple groups of Lie type](https://books.google.com/books?id=nW9tPZUMkdIC) or Proposition 1.2.3 of Adler's [Refined anisotropic $K$-types …](http://msp.berkeley.edu/pjm/1998/185-1/p01.xhtml).

Comment: Yes, I took $T$ to be maximal torus of the Borel subgroup(like in the Bruhat decomposition). By this construction $\sigma \in W \simeq S_n$, $p_σ$ should be the matrix with $1$ on the $(σ(i), i)-entry$ for every $1 ≤ i ≤ n − 1$, $(−1)^{n+1}$ on the $(σ(n), n)-entry$ and zero elsewhere and the longest Weyl element "in" $G$ is $p_{σ_{(12..n)}}$. I'm aware of Chevalley's commutator formula, but I was unsuccessful in finding a general way to move down a root element in Chevalley groups.

Comment: If it helps I took the example from this article:[ Meiri - Generating pairs for finite index subgroups of $SL(n,Z)$][1]  *page 3* which I'm trying to expand.


  [1]: https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07798

Comment: I guess you mean $(-1)^{\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)}$, not $(-1)^{n + 1}$, for the $(\sigma(n), n)$ entry; otherwise your matrix doesn't lie in $\operatorname{SL}_n$ when $n$ is even and $\sigma$ is the identity.  I also guess your notation $\sigma_{(1 2 \ldots n)}$ means just $(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)$, an $n$-cycle; this is not the longest element of the Weyl group but a Coxeter element, which has length $n$.  The longest element is $(1\ n)(2\ n - 1)(3\ n - 2)\dotsb$, which has length $n(n - 1)/2$.  (Also notice you've mislabelled your root system; it's $A_{n - 1}$, not $A_n$.)

Comment: Note, though, that what you have described produces matrices in $\operatorname{SL}_n$, but not a subgroup; for example, in $\operatorname{SL}_2$, the identity element of the Weyl group lifts as the identity matrix, but the non-identity element lifts as $n = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, whose square is not the identity matrix.  Further, conjugation by the lift of the Weyl element doesn't behave as you want; if $x_{i, j}(t)$ is the matrix with $1$s on the diagonal, $t$ in the $(i, j)$ spot, and $0$ elsewhere, then $n x_{1, 2}(t)n^{-1}$ equals $x_{2, 1}(-t)$, not $x_{2, 1}(t)$.

Comment: There is a lift of the Weyl group to the whole group that experiences at most this sign issue—the group it generates covers the Weyl group with a 2-torsion kernel, and is called the Tits group (not [that one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tits_group))—but, as already the example of $\operatorname{SL}_2$ shows, the sign *is* (sometimes) unavoidable.

Comment: For your actual question, though, I'm puzzled.  If $\tilde\alpha$ is the highest root, then there is a sequence $(\alpha_i)_{i = 1}^{h - 1}$ of simple roots such that $\sum_{i = 1}^j \alpha_i$ is a root for all $j$, and $\sum_{i = 1}^{h - 1} \alpha_i = \tilde\alpha$; then the commutator of an element of the highest-root group with an element of the $-\alpha_{h - 1}$ root group lies in root group of height strictly less than $h - 1$—to find out which one, use the Chevalley formula—and you may proceed essentially by induction.  What more are you looking for?

Comment: (Correction:  while correcting a misnumbering [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338323/nontrivial-relations-of-the-irreducible-root-systems#comment846276_338323), I made the same mistake; the length (as opposed to order) of a Coxeter element is $n - 1$, not $n$.)

Comment: Thank you for correcting my example, about your answer: how can I know there such a sequence? also from the Chevalley formula isn't any commutator of an element of the highest-root group with an element of a positive root group is the identity? (because  $ht(i\tildeα+jα)>ht(\tildeα)$)

Comment: Certainly the highest root is some sum of simple roots.   Its product with one of those simple roots, say $\alpha_{h - 1}$, must be strictly positive, but then $\tilde\alpha - \alpha_{h - 1}$ is a root (this is a standard result about root systems; say, in Bourbaki).  You are right that the highest-root group commutes with every *positive*-root group; that's why I suggested using the *negative*-root group corresponding to $-\alpha_{h - 1}$.  (This is the same thing you do in $\operatorname{SL}_n$, by taking the commutator with the $\alpha_{i, 1}$ root group.)

Comment: My assumption is that I only have one root group(from the example my guess was the highest root group) and elements of the big Bruhat cell(hence I can get to the longest Weyl element) to work with and try to build up to $U_+$(the positive root subgroup). So either I have the highest root elements or simple root elements to work with but not both.

Comment: It's really important here whether you want to talk about the *longest* element (the one with a representative in the big cell $B w_0 B$) or a *Coxeter* element (one you keep using).  Anyway, it sounds like you have a question in mind that's not quite the one you asked, so I think it would be a good idea to formulate *precisely* what you have in mind, and ask that as a new question.